# Tips to save space in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, diskspace

Various mongodb services meters by disk use. What are some tips for saving space when working with mongodb?

Thanks.

Comment: @xenoterracide: I certainly hope you do, that was flat out trolling and completely unhelpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is really rather vague. Some things which may or may not apply to you (in no particular order):

#### Shorten verbose field names

This is best illustrated with an example:

```
{
    surname: "Smith",
    forename: "John",
    location: { grid_e: 100.02, grid_n: 450.08 }
}
```

The previous document could be shortened by removing unnecessary wordiness in the various field names.

```
{
    sn: "Smith",
    fn: "John",
    loc: { e: 100.02, n: 450.08 }
}
```

This will give you a very tiny saving in space, but it will be multiplied by the size of each document (number of fields) and the number of documents (could become significant if you have millions). Here is a [superb post](http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/23/on-shortened-field-names-in-mongodb/) discussing the benefits and drawbacks of this method.

#### Capped Collections

Capped collections allow you to specify a limit to how many documents you wish to store. It works in a first-in-first-out manner (oldest documents will be discarded). This is particularly applicable if you are logging and wish to store the most recent `x` documents, but old ones have no relevance.

There are some caveats to the use of capped collections. See the [MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) for full details.

#### Consider your documents' relationships

Documents can either have embedded documents or relationships to other documents (in other collections) foreign-key style. The pros and cons of each approach are [discussed](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference) [frequently](http://www.10gen.com/event_schemadesign_10apr27), but ultimately it is for you to choose which approach works for you.

Taking the example of a blog, it may be that each blog post has an author. You could either embed this author information within each post, or you might choose to put them in their own `authors` or `users` collection. The latter approach would save space, particularly if many users often make many posts (rather than just one or two). Be aware that you will incur an extra database call since there are no joins.

#### Edit: Expanding on Relationships

Relationships between documents can be done in a couple of ways in addition to embedding them. You could just use the ID of the related document like so (reusing the blog example above):

```
{
    _id: <whatever>,
    title: "Document Relationships in MongoDB",
    body: "bla bla bla bla",
    // ...
    user_id: <id of the user document>
}
```

And in the `users` collection, that related document would exist:

```
{
    _id: <whatever>,
    name: "Mark Embling",
    email: "example@markembling.info",
    ///...
}
```

This is probably the simplest possible approach to relationships (besides embedding them), but it will be up to you to maintain it within your own code *entirely*. You will need to make the call to grab the related user when you need it, and to update it whenever that might be necessary. That said, I see nothing wrong with this approach, and have seen it used on a few occasions.

A similar approach is to use DBRef. This is a more formal method for describing a relationship like the above. Instead of just putting the ID of the other document in, you specify a DBRef which is a sort of reference to another document, formalized. I hope that makes sense. Both approaches I have described here are [discussed in detail](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References) in the mongodb docs. It is worth noting that manual references will take up (slightly) less space than a DBRef, since a DBRef holds extra (possibly redundant) information, such as which collection is referred to. It has the advantage of being supported natively by many of the driver libs though, so it makes your life that little bit easier.

Ultimately, what methods work and are relevant depend on what it is you are trying to do. Consider the options, the tradeoff and make the call as to whether its something you should do. And experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the great post. I understand that document relationships is a popular topic, but for the sake of this answer being a comprehensive resource, could you go over that again here with examples? Thanks.

Comment: strange, I always say an extra collection as a tradeoff diskspace for better performance. Imagine wanting to query for all blog posts, comments, forum posts, votes etc made by a certain user. (eg graph like queries). That works well if there is a collection of users with references to all these things. That creates a bit of diskspace overhead, but then there seems to be a lot of room for diskspace improvement in mongodb by using more efficient ids as well as not storing text keys to compensate the loss. Whatever floats your boat...

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid duplicating data and possibly use some form of compression if storing large amounts of data that does not need to be searchable.

Comment: Any suggestions inregards to the compression?

Comment: Unfortunatlly not, I have not done any inprocess compression my self.

Comment: If you wanted to store a body of text (for example), the [DEFLATE](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951.html) compression method might be suitable? It seems relatively easy to find resources on using it from various languages ( [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Zlib/Deflate.html), [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php), ...). Might suit you depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

i think good way is use one document for related data

for example if you have user collection you can give document to each user and in this document implant other things like avatar or acl and other things